# load mypage.php via ajax into a div in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i have an ajax load request working in wordpress, but i would like to load the content from another page into the container div. at the moment it just passes the url in $dataToSend as a string?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var $dataToSend = "my-page.php";
    var $testBtn = jQuery('#text-ajax-btn');
    var $holdingCtn = jQuery('#my-holding-ctn');

    $testBtn.click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data:{
                action:'myAjax',
                dataToSend:$dataToSend,
            },
            success: function(data,textStatus,XMLHttpRequest){
                $holdingCtn.html("");
                $holdingCtn.append(data);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

how can i pass an entire .php page through as the $dataTosend?

Comment: url: myAjax.ajaxurl shouldnt this contain my-page.php? I think you are doing opposite of what you want to do :) why °sending° when obviously want to load something in the current page?

Comment: thanks, have tried this and now i get an error:
'500 (Internal Server Error)' in the console. the url looks to be correct.
im pretty new to ajax in wordpress, is this because im on a local server 'mamp'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time for wordpress, give me a sec to access my repository and I will show you example code.

I think problem is your my-page.php! I imagine you custom coded it. So it doesn't have necessary functions loaded.

put following code at the top of your my-page.php (this will help with 500 error you are getting)

```
require('../../../wp-load.php');
```

ajax part should look something like this:

```
//start ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/wp-content/themes/theme/my-page.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    console.dir(data);

                }
            })
```

Comment: this worked for me, just adding "require('../../../wp-load');" to the top of the page to be loaded actually made it possible to use the shorthand jQuery('#my-ctn').load('my-page.php'); thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load content from `my-page.php` file then you can load from the server side using

```
$data = file_get_contents('path/to/file/my-page.php'); // pass right path/url
```

Then, just echo the content from your function (registered ajax handler in WordPress using add_action) and in this case it should be

```
echo $data;
die(); // terminate the further execution
```

So, it should look something like

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myAjax', 'yourAjaxHandler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjax', 'yourAjaxHandler' );
function yourAjaxHandler(){
    $data = file_get_contents('path/to/file/my-page.php');
    die($data); // echo out the string and terminates execution
}
```

In your `success` callback, you can use

```
success: function(data){
    jQuery('#my-holding-ctn').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Here is a good read [about ajax](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) in `WordPress`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is fully applicable, but the super easy way is just

```
$("#myDiv").load("myFile.php?foo=1&bar=2...");
```

Comment: yeah this was my first approach, but couldnt get this to work either. I actually ended up at the same point when hardcoding the url for the page in i got the same '500 (Internal Server Error)' which makes me think its to do with being on a localhost?

Comment: Your approach is nice but not appropriate for wordPress, In `WordPress` you need to do it via `admin-ajax.php/myAjax.ajaxurl` file and using ajax `hooks`.

Comment: Here is a good read [about ajax](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) in `WordPress`

Comment: @user2805371 if you were seeing 500s, then that means the request was being made (e.g., your ajax logic is fine) and something was wrong with the request or the file you were calling.